# Auto scrolling carousel in webkit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, carousel

Environment : self-made Webkit based browser
Test environment : success => firefox , Chrome

I have made a auto and seamless carousel news widget ,**just like TV news** . It runs fine in firefox and chrome , but not in my own browser . The news stop and doesn't run.

How the widget works? It's pretty easy , just to detect the div's position and add constantly to show like TV . Once the msg is out of bond of window, it will be updated by ajax and re-position to the beginning .

Almost the same as this : 
http://codecanyon.net/item/jnewsticker-jquery-news-ticker/full_screen_preview/2137525

I'm wondering if there's some webkit setting I didn't enable or disable...

Please kindly help .

Comment: Please provide more information -- a minimal demo at the very least.  (It sounds like a re-implementation of [`<marquee>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee)?)

Comment: Exactly like <marquee> , 
thanks ,  I will try to implement it and see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

When I try to set the position of DOM per 10 ms , I always re-check the position in the same time. However, right before I get the originally position , it's already set to new value. That's why the position always stick on the same point.